# Deriving from streambuf without rewriting a corresponding stream

Tags: c++, stream, fstream, mmap, streambuf

Some days ago, I decided that it would be fun to write a `streambuf` subclass that would use `mmap` and read-ahead.
I looked at how my STL (SGI) implemented `filebuf` and realized that `basic_filebuf` contains a `FILE*`. So inheriting from `basic_filebuf` is out of the question.

So I inherited from `basic_streambuf`. Then i wanted to bind my `mmapbuf` to a fstream.

I thought the only thing that I would have to do would be to copy the implicit interface of `filebuf`... but that was a clear mistake. In the SGI, `basic_fstream` owns a `basic_filebuf`. No matter if I call `basic_filestream.std::::ios::rdbuf( streambuf* )`, the filestream completely ignores it and uses its own `filebuf`.

So now I'm a bit confused... sure, I can create my own `mmfstream`, that would be the exact copy/paste of the `fstream` but that sounds really not DRY-oriented.

What I can't understand, is: **why does `fstream` is so tightly coupled with `filebuf`, so that it is not possible to use anything else than a `filebuf`?** The whole point of separating streams and bufs is that one can use a stream with a different buffer.

Solutions:

=> `filestream` should rely on the implicit interface of `filebuf`. That is, fstream should be templated by a streambuf class. That would allow everyone to provide its own streambuf subclass to a `fstream` as long as it implements `filebuf`'s implicit interface. Problem: we cannot add a template parameter to `fstream` since it would break template selectors while using `fstream` as template template parameter.

=> `filebuf` should be a pure virtual class without any additional attributes. So that one can inherit from it without carrying all its FILE* garbage.

Your ideas on the subject ?

Comment: You have a typo in the subject; streambug => streambuf. Don't know the answer to your question though, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [mapped_file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html#mapped_file) in the [Boost.Iostreams](http://://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library. I've never used used it myself, but it seems like it might already do what you need.

EDIT: Oops, reread your questions and I see you're doing this for fun. Perhaps you can draw inspiration from Boost.Iostreams?

Comment: Yeah I chatted with a colleague this morning and he informed me too that boost already have it :) But as you noticed, that's mainly for fun! Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In the IO streams' design, most of the actual streams' functionality (as opposed to the stream buffers' functionality) is implemented in `std::basic_istream`, `std::basic_ostream`, and their base classes. *The string and file stream classes are more or less just convenience wrappers which make sure a stream with the right type of buffer is instantiated*.

If you want to extend the streams, *you almost always want to provide your **own stream buffer class***, and you almost never need to provide your own stream class. .

Once you have your own stream buffer type, you can then make it the buffer for any stream object you happen to have around. Or you derive your own classes from `std::basic_istream`, `std::basic_ostream`, and `std::basic_iostream` which instantiates your stream buffer and pass it to their base classes.
The latter is more convenient for users, but requires you to write some boiler-plate code for the buffer's instantiation (namely constructors for the stream class).

To answer your question: File streams and file buffer are coupled so tightly because the former only exists to ease the creation of the latter. Using a file stream makes it easy to set it all up.
Using your own stream class to wrap construction of your own stream buffer shouldn't be a problem, since you shouldn't be passing around file streams anyway, but only (references) to the base classes.

Comment: Because you did not answered the question. Nothing written here helps in any way to solve the problem. That is like you are speaking to yourself, answering an imaginary "what is the difference between iostream and streambuf" question...

Comment: @Aurélien: Fair point, except that I certainly _meant_ to answer your question. I have tried to change the answer so that this becomes more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

`fstream` in itself is not a big class. It inherits from `basic_stream` to provide support for all the `<<` and `>>` operations, contains a specialized `steambuf` that have to be initialized, and the corresponding constructors to pass the parameters to the `streambuf` constructor.

In a sense, what you wrote about your templated solution is OK. But `basic_stream` can also be derived into a `tcp_stream` for example. In that case, the constructors of `fstream` are a bit useless. Thus you need to provide a new `tcpstream` class, inheriting from `basic_stream` with the correct parameters for the constructors to be able to create the `tcp_stream`. In the end, you wouldn't use anything from `fstream`. Creating this new `tcpstream` is a matter of writing 3 or 4 functions only.

In the end, you would derive from the `fstream` class without any real reason to. This would add more coupling in the class hierarchy, unneeded coupling.

Comment: I totally agree with the tcp_stream thing, since a tcp stream cannot be manipulated like a file stream nor a string stream. But here, we are speaking of two streambuffers that should be accessed in the exact same way: they both manipulate files, and should both be accessed by filestream. What is the point of having fstream and a filebuf in different classes if you can't use one without the other ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will need to provide additional parameters (more than the ones given to `filebuf`) to your new `streambuf`. Thus, you will have to write new constructors for your new `filestream`. These constructors are the only thing you'll have to write, to create it, be it by deriving, or being standalone.

Comment: > No, i'll have to implement all the fstream additional features: open, close, is_open, ... And, the problem is not writing these little methods, it's just I shouldn't have to do it. This will be a copy/paste, no code reuse. More importantly, my users will have to switch from fstream to mmfstream, that should not be.

Comment: Because you could use the other without the one!

Comment: @sbi: fair point, didn't read it that way. Comment and downvote deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `std::fstream` is that it is a _**F**_ile based `std::stream`. If you want an ordinary `std::stream` backed by your `mmstreambuf`, then you should create a `mmstreambuf` and pass it to `std::stream::stream(std::streambuf*)`

Comment: "The whole point of std::fstream is that it is a _F_ile based std::stream" > And I **want** a file based stream! My `mmstreambuf` class provides the exact same features of a `filebuf`, but using mapped memory instead of buffered memory.